# ImageButton and TextView different states

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, imagebutton

I have a set of Views consisting in an ImageButton, an ImageView and a TextView.
The code looks like this:

```
 <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imagebutton_com"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/bean_bg" 
            />

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/imageview_arrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/arrow_1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            />

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/textview_wizard_main_button"
            android:text="Soybeans"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageview_arrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            />
```

All works as expected, but I want to change the textColor of the TextView when the Button is focused.

I tried writing a selector xml file to do the same, but nothing worked.
Any suggestion?

Comment: A selector only operates on the active View. You can't use it to change the text color of another View. You should accept @waqastam's answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it in code. Use **OnFocusChangeListener** on your ImageButton to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder color under resources and add selector.xml file to that folder

change property of `TextView` namely

`android:textColor = "@color/white"`

to

```
android:textColor = "@color/selector"
```

Comment: It won't work. A selector only operates on the active View. You can't use it to change the text color of another View - as the OP requested.